Spotify API to get real-time insights
I am a self taught data analyst from Industrial and Manufacturing Engineering background, I want to use Spotify API to get real-time analysis or make a real dashboard to know important insights like which song is trending in which region, which playlist is trending, which artist is generating the most revenue in specific region etc. The purpose of this is to track real-time solutions and insights for daily tracking for music businesses or corporations. I would be very grateful if you could guide me more on this.
I tried connecting spotify api, I want a roadmap on how can I complete what I am having vision for.

The roadmap is the Spotify API doc

Also, please take the tour, read How to Ask, and then post a proper minimal reproducible example with all relevant details. Also, read this Why is "Can someone help me?" not a useful question?
